# Read a JSON Dictionary SWIFT

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

How can I take the values from the json dictionary in swift?
This is the json

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nome": "Federico",
        "cognome": "Loro",
        "data": "1999-07-12"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "nome": "pippo",
        "cognome": "vtuij",
        "data": "0000-00-00"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "nome": "Christian",
        "cognome": "Loro",
        "data": "2018-02-25"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "nome": "pippo",
        "cognome": "vtuij",
        "data": "0000-00-00"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "nome": "pippo",
        "cognome": "vtuij",
        "data": "0000-00-00"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "nome": "pippo",
        "cognome": "vtuij",
        "data": "0000-00-00"
    }
]
```

My problem is that I don't know how to access into the dictionary.

Comment: Note that  `"0000-00-00"` it is not a valid date. Btw SO it is not a code writing service.

Comment: Show some code which you have tried

Comment: Please search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+parse+json There are more than 3000 related questions.

Comment: By the way, that's an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your JSON values seem to be strings, so you should create a codable struct like this:

```
// name this properly!
struct MyStruct : Codable {
    let id: String
    let nome: String
    let cognome: String
    let data: String
}
```

Now you can create a `JSONDecoder`:

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let decoded = try! jsonDecoder.decode([MyStruct].self, from: yourJSONString.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Now you can, for example, get the first item's `id`:

```
decoded.first!.id
```

Comment: Response is : Cannot use instance member 'jsonDecoder' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: @YouFred try declaring `jsonDecoder` as a local variable instead of at class-level.

Comment: Could I make this? let JSONString = "http://localhost:8888/ProLife/api/selectteam.php"

Comment: @YouFred that is not your JSON string. That's the URL you are requesting. Get the data from the response like you did in your answer, but instead of using `JSONSerialization`, use a `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: If I convert JSON in a string?

Comment: If you have the JSON as `Data` already, pass that directly to `decode`. Otherwise call `data(using:)` on the JSON string. @YouFred